# Laravel - Serialization of Job to be processed on remote system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

## Introduction / System Architecture

- Server A - Laravel Installation, Database A
- Server B - RabbitMQ Server
- Server C - Laravel Installation, Database B

*Server A* is an API Endpoint, only receiving calls from remote sources. Depending on the call, it'll add a job to the RabbitMQ Server (*Server B*), which in turn is processed/listened to by *Server C*.

*Server A* contains a local copy of the exact same job that is processed by *Server C*. The job handler code and constructor are shown below (**Job Code**).

**The Issue:**
Server A can not serialize the job and add it to the queue, as it attempts to access information about a monitor that only exists in Database B (*Server C*). *Server A* has a copy of the model, but does not contain the actual database tables or records as it has no use for them - it's only meant to serialize the job and say "This is what *you* (*Server C*) should be doing."

However, upon issuing the job, it's also attempting to fetch database information (likely to serialize the exact data that will be required), which it fails to do as the records don't exist there.

My understanding of Laravel's `SerializesModels` was specifically that it would only serialize the model call itself, without actually doing anything database related. This does not appear to function, or I am misunderstanding/using it incorrectly - although very little documentation appears to be available.

**Workarounds:** One possible workaround would be to simply give *Server A* access to the database on *Server C*. This is in this case not an option, as it would break the design which is intended for high availability (where the API endpoint and queue should never be unavailable, but where the queue processor might be).

[image: TopDown View]

## The code

**Relevant Job Code**

```
// Models
use App\UptimeMonitor;

// Notifications
use App\Notifications\StatusQueue as StatusNotification;

class StatusQueue implements ShouldQueue
{
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

        protected $monitor_source;
        protected $monitor_data;
        protected $monitor_repository;

        /**
         * Create a new job instance.
         *
         * @param string[] monitor_source (Eg: HetrixTools)
         * @param array[] monitor_data (All data passed from the source)
         *
         */
        public function __construct($monitor_source, array $monitor_data)
        {
            $this->monitor_source = $monitor_source;
            $this->monitor_data = $monitor_data;

            if($this->monitor_source === 'centric')
                    return $this->centric();

        }

        /**
         * Centric Uptime Monitoring
         */
        public function centric()
        {
                $result = ($this->monitor_data['monitor_status'] == 'online') ? 'online' : 'timeout';

                try {
                        $monitor = UptimeMonitor::where('identifier', '=', $this->monitor_data['monitor_id'])->firstOrFail();
                        $status = $monitor->status()->firstOrFail();
                        $contacts = $monitor->contacts()->get();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                        return Log::error('[JOBS::StatusQueue::centric] - ' . $e);
                }

                $status->state = $result;

                if(!$contacts)
                        return true;

                foreach($contacts as $contact) {
                        $contact->notify(new StatusNotification($monitor, $status));
                }
        }
}
```

## Other code

If you do require any other code, let me know! This should however cover the entire functionality of the job class itself. Other than that, all that's happening is issuing that job - and how that's done is obvious based on the constructor.

## Question

The final question from all of this: Why is this failing (as in; why can it not serialize the job, without needing the database information?) - and do you see a way to work around this issue, to where I do not need access to the database from *Server C* to queue the job from *Server A*, still using Laravel's Queue mechanics?

Much obliged, as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the easiest solution is almost always the right one.

**Server A does not need to have a replica of the job that Server B will process** - it can have a completely empty job with the same class, and server B will still process it correctly.

As a result, this is now the Job on Server A:

```
class AlertQueue implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $job;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Whilst Server B also has an AlertQueue job, which has all of the logic that will actually get performed.